# "Endless adapter". How to remove bulk items from RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement an Endless Adapter style RecyclerView. I'm providing an OnScrollListener that requests more content as the user reaches the upper and lower bounds of the data set.

Because the data set is expected to contain as many as 10k-30k items, I'm attempting to only keep a couple of hundred items at any time. The problem I'm experiencing is that the RecyclerView generates an exception when trimming the data. These are the custom methods inside my Adapter.

```
public void addToStart(final MyObject[] newItems) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.addAll(0,Arrays.asList(newItems));
            trimEnd(newItems.length);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}

public void addToEnd(final MyObject[] newItems) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            items.addAll(Arrays.asList(newItems));
            trimStart(newItems.length);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


}

private void trimStart(int trimAmount) {
    items = items.subList(items.size() - trimAmount, items.size());
}

private void trimEnd(int trimAmount) {
    items = items.subList(0, items.size() - trimAmount);
}
```

When scrolling after items has been updated. The following error is thrown.

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid
>   item position 90(offset:90).state:100
>          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4320)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4278)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1947)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:434)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1322)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1150)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(LinearLayoutManager.java:1007)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(RecyclerView.java:1355)
>          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2209)
>          at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8393)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2426)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
>          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
>          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
>          at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2749)
>          at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>          at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
>          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
>          at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8583)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4091)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3957)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3638)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5806)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5745)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5716)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
>          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
>          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java)
>          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:183)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:5867)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5919)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

If I do not shrink the items array, instead just adding to it. The RecyclerView shows the growing data set as expected. All the examples I've seen online only show adding items. Is there no way to keep the data size contained other than paging where the adapter is recreated as the user scrolled to the upper/lower bounds?

Comment: How about pushing all this data in DB and using CursorAdapter/Loader which will fetch data from DB. Will this approach work for you?

Comment: The items are gathered from a network db. Would creating an on-device DB to store the items as I request them allow me to shrink the data set?

Comment: It won't shrink the dataset but consistency will be maintained.